# Connecting to specific ip and port

Tags: networking, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

This summer I am working at a computer summer camp. All the kids love playing slither.io

The kids really want to play on the same world but slither.io doesn't provide an easy way to do this and instead spreads them out through the multiple servers. I have limited networking knowledge but am somewhat familiar to working with webSockets.

What I was hoping I could do to get them on the same world was:
Have one kid connect to slither.io and enter a game. 
Once they were in open the dev tools in Chrome and get the ip and port that they were connected to with bso.ip and bso.po
The other kids could then using the dev tools run

```
connect("ws:\\123.123.123.123:444")
```

with the ip and port set to whatever the first kid had.

Running connect gets them into slither.io but 90% of the time it is on a different server/ip address

Is there a way to get them all in the same world?

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to the WebSocket alone is not enough to register the game to use it. Looking at the source code, there is a function `forceServer`, which sets the IP and Port:

```
function forceServer (a, b) {
 sos = [];
 forcing = true;
 bso = {};
 bso.ip = a;
 bso.po = b;
 bso.ac = 999;
 sos.push(bso);
}
```

The `sos` array is global and used later on to connect to the WebSocket and register the game instance. The exact details are difficult to follow because it's all minified in `game73gig.js`, but I think this function sets everything up.

Run the following in the Console instead:

```
forceServer("123.123.123.123", "443");
```

There is a Tampermonkey snippet to inject a form element and JavaScript to do this automatically. I haven't tried it but it's called [Slitherio-Plugin](https://github.com/Montaron/Slitherio-Plugin).